# How do I get the Clientcertificate with GRPC Java?

Tags: java, server, certificate, netty, grpc

I have a Java Server Application, which gets Data from GRPC clients via TLS and handles it on the server. Now I want to work with multiple clients. To allocate the recieved events with the clients, I want to read the client certificate and allocate the events with the DN of the certificate. How can I get the client certificate?

I found this to build the Server: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#mutual-tls

```
Server server = NettyServerBuilder.forPort(8443)
.addService(new ServerService())
.sslContext(GrpcSslContexts.forServer(certChainFile, privateKeyFile)
    .trustManager(clientCAsFile)
    .clientAuth(ClientAuth.REQUIRE)
    .build())
    .intercept(new AuthorizationInterceptor())
    .build();
```

And then you should implement a server interceptor

```
public final static Context.Key<SSLSession> SSL_SESSION_CONTEXT =  Context.key("SSLSession");
@Override
public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call,
Metadata headers, ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
SSLSession sslSession = call.getAttributes().get(Grpc.TRANSPORT_ATTR_SSL_SESSION);
if (sslSession == null) {
    return next.startCall(call, headers);
}
return Contexts.interceptCall(
    Context.current().withValue(SSL_SESSION_CONTEXT, sslSession), call, headers, next);
```

}

I made a new Class AuthorizationInterceptor where I implemented the interface ServerInterceptor and the override the method interceptCall above, and want to get the certificate in this way in my Service class:

```
SSLSession sslSession = AuthorizationInterceptor.SSL_SESSION_CONTEXT.get();
sslSession.getPeerCertificateChain()[0].getSubjectDN();
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, I forgot to bind in the interceptor in the server builder. The code above is working now!